# validation in edit text of age in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, validation

hello i hope you all doing good

i have problem with validation i tried many methods but none are working

i have edit text  i want put validation that allow only entering number from 1 to 15 only but its not working any help pls

```
 String pet_name=petname.getText().toString();
            String pet_type=ptype.getText().toString();
            String pet_age=page.getText().toString();
            String pet_gender=pgender.getText().toString();
            String pet_location=plocation.getText().toString();
            String pet_des=pdes.getText().toString();
            String pet_img=petimg.getText().toString();
            int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(page.getText().toString());



 if(pet_name.equals(""))
                petname.setError("User name Should not be empty");
            else if(!pet_name.matches(namevalid))
                petname.setError("Should be Only letters");
            else if(pet_type.equals(""))
                ptype.setError("Should not be empty");
            else if(!pet_type.startsWith("Cat")&& !pet_type.startsWith("Dog"))
                ptype.setError("Should be Only Cat or Dog");
            else if(pet_age.equals(""))
                page.setError("Should not be empty");
              else if (inputInt <= 15 && inputInt >= 1 ) ;
            page.setError("Should be be between 1 to 15 year");
```

the problem is here when i add this code program stop working

```
    else if (inputInt <= 15 && inputInt >= 1 ) ;
            page.setError("Should be be between 1 to 15 year");



enter code here
```

Comment: Condition should be else if (inputInt >= 16 || inputInt < 1 )

Answer (score 1):

i fixed thx to all

when i was adding age code other validation under age stop working so i put all codes inside age validation and now its working

```
  else if(!page.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                //check to see if the entered donation is superior to 5 if so go to make payment page
                int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(page.getText().toString());
                if (inputInt <= 10 && inputInt >= 1) {
                      if(pet_gender.equals(""))
                        pgender.setError("Should not be empty");
                    else if(!pet_gender.startsWith("Male")&& !pet_gender.startsWith("Female"))
                        pgender.setError("Should be Only Male or Female");
                    else if(pet_location.equals(""))
                        plocation.setError("Should not be empty");
                    else if(pet_des.equals(""))
                        pdes.setError("Should not be empty");
                    else if(pet_img.equals(""))
                        petimg.setError("Should not be empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to do this?

```
else if (inputInt >= 15 || inputInt <= 1 ) ;
            page.setError("Should be be between 1 to 15 year");
```

Comment: yeah by mistake i wrote the wrong code ......but still i have error :(

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is like this

```
  else if (inputInt >= 10 && inputInt <= 1 )
```

In above condition, You are using &&(AND) operator. Means both the condition shoulde be true(left one and right one). And these both will never true as You also know.(value of `inputInt` would not be >10 as well as <1 at same time)

So You need ||(OR) operator. Your condition would be like this

```
else if (inputInt < 1 || inputInt > 15 ) 
    page.setError("Should be be between 1 to 15 year");
```

Comment: Wont this give the inputInt to be greater than 15 and less than 1. User wants number between 1 and 15

Comment: @lyncx This is for validation. Means when inputInt is greater than 15 or less than 1 then OP can show a message that the number should be in range of 1 to 15. This condition will detect if number is not in the given range

Comment: Right, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Please expand what is the error you receiving,

for better coding, try to change:

```
int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(page.getText().toString());
```

to:

```
int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(pet_age);
```

because you already received the text inside the edit text of page, pulling it again will be repetitive and unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
else if(!page.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                //check to see if the entered donation is superior to 5 if so go to make payment page
                int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(page.getText().toString());
                if (inputInt <= 10 && inputInt >= 1) {
                      if(pet_gender.equals(""))
                        pgender.setError("Should not be empty");
                    else if(!pet_gender.startsWith("Male")&& !pet_gender.startsWith("Female"))
                        pgender.setError("Should be Only Male or Female");
                    else if(pet_location.equals(""))
                        plocation.setError("Should not be empty");
                    else if(pet_des.equals(""))
                        pdes.setError("Should not be empty");
                    else if(pet_img.equals(""))
                        petimg.setError("Should not be empty");``
```